# How did I get a signed cert back with a wildcard common name when I submitted a csr with a specific common name?

Tags: certificates, wildcard

Apologies if this is obvious but I'm hoping for some clarification here.  I generated a CSR on an appliance of mine.  This CSR had a specific common name (let's call it foo.domain.com).  I then sent the CSR off to my cert group.  They provided a signed certificate but the common name was a wildcard (*.domain.com) and the initial common name I used/expected was listed under subject alternative names.

When I compared the modulo between the cert and csr, they matched so I know that they're cryptographically associated with one another.

This doesn't make sense. I thought that the common name for a signed cert has to exactly match the common name included in a given csr.  Is this not the case?